# TinyMCE 4 Issues on IE 11

Tags: tinymce, internet-explorer-11, tinymce-4

I have recently updated some admin systems on websites to use TinyMCE 4, using the JS version.
I have just discovered a bug that only occurs in IE11, which is the following:

When a Textarea loads it contains the posted html data, but then after the split second it takes for TinyMCE to trigger, all the content within the Textarea is hidden - and TinyMCE is just empty.

It seems to work on all other browsers, including other versions of Internet Explorer. Has anyone else had this issue and know of a solution?

Cheers

Comment: can u create a fiddle?

Comment: Let me guess, the problem is probably caused by the content, maybe some unmatched html tag.. but it's difficult to tell without providing sample code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TinyMCE Editor doesn't update the hidden field in IE11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27502394/tinymce-editor-doesnt-update-the-hidden-field-in-ie11)

Answer (score 0):

We've fixed this bug since then. Updating to the latest version should fix this.