# TinyMCE Editor doesn't update the hidden field in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using TinyMCE as a HTML editor for a CMS.

This has been working fine and the form submits the correct data as it should in Chrome. It also displays correctly in IE 11. If I submit the form with IE11 however, the browser doesn't POST the data from the form.

Checking the source code, the hidden field doesn't get filled out with the new data entered into the textbox. I couldn't find any information on this, and it is happening on multiple computers.

Does anyone know enough about TinyMCE to know what the issue could be?

For those who don't know about it:

> TinyMCE, also known as the Tiny Moxiecode Content Editor, is a platform-independent web-based JavaScript/HTML WYSIWYG editor control, released as open source software under the LGPL by Moxiecode Systems AB. It has the ability to convert HTML textarea fields or other HTML elements to editor instances.
>   It offers HTML formatting tools, like bold, italic, underline, both ordered and unordered lists, different types of alignments, in-line placement of images and videos, etc. It is highly useful for those who want to allow their users to edit HTML documents online. The different options can be configured at the time of integration with a project, which improves the flexibility of a project.

It works by replacing the textarea field with an iframe which gives a number of HTML editing controls for the user, and places this data into a hidden text field which allows the data to be submitted.

Comment: Down voters please explain rather than just vote.

Comment: It is unclear what you want us to do. What exactly is your question?

Comment: My previous comment seems to have made you quite angry. Consider the situation for a while -- you're saying one of the plugins you use has problems working on IE11. How are we supposed to help you? We're not TinyMCE's maintainers, and your question does not contain the relevant information (i.e. *code*) that would allow us to work on the problem.

Comment: Obviously they want help with why the POST data isn't sent with IE11!

Comment: @shaw, fine. *How are we supposed to help?* Does the questioner want us to debug TinyMCE for them? In that case, that's not how this site works.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Usually by adding the TinyMCE to the title people that know about it would comment. I hate to have to submit links all about TinyMCE for someone to help. Sorry I know this sounds like I'm being ungrateful. Slightly desperate as I need to present this in a few hours from now.

Comment: Yes a fair point but simply down voting someone's question makes SO seem like an unfriendly place. Why not just ask for some code?

Comment: @user, I understand your situation, but my point is that if TinyMCE does not support IE11 then there isn't much we can do. If it does support it and the bug comes from your code, then you should post the relevant parts of that code so we have something to work with.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi It should be supported by everything. "TinyMCE is compatible with multiple browsers, including Internet Explorer, Mozilla Firefox, Safari, Opera and Google Chrome, across multiple operating systems."

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I managed to fix by downgrading to an older version. Very odd as the version 3 is advertised as being non-compatible and version 4 was suppose to be compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have manged to "fix" the IE11 compatibility issue by downgrading to TinyMCE 3.

Answer (score 0):

I was having issues validating text box after we upgrade to IE11, it was working fine on IE9, but following link just fixed it like a magic.

Please follow this link and hopefully it should work, as it worked for me.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1545148.aspx?RequiredFieldValidator+with+tinyMCE